# Integrating an external API at shipping section on bigcommerce

Tags: ajax, bigcommerce

My supplier offers an API to check programmatically shipping fees in real-time . His API can work with any system that supports https protocol and can be used with any programming language.

By preparing data to upload into BC, I faced an issue in shipping fees calculation on how it can be displayed to customers. The option of flat rate or free shipping can't work for me since we target worldwide destination and not for a specific country.

So, my questions are as follow:

- Is it possible to customize the shipping section by integrating the
  supplier's API, and display shipping fees from there based on the
  entered delivery address?
- If so, these displayed shipping fees can
  be added programmatically to the total price of the order ?
- In that case, which programming languages are allowed by BC to achieve this
  goal?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!